# ws-discovery: how to obtain services in the central repository (Governance Registry), with their real names and not Discovered-3442536235?

Tags: esb, wso2

The services deployed on Application Server (AS) are not being stored in the tool WSO2 Governance Registry with their real names.
What to do to come up with the same names that have been deployed in AS?
For example, the service implemented xxx appear on WSO2 Governance Registry named Discovered-2409424825

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ws-discovery, we keep service name to UUID mapping..ServiceID is the auto generated UUID.User could not change this.But he can define the valid URI for scopes.. In the scope you can keep the service name, so it is easy to identify..

Comment: ok but the field relates to the scope (namespace) is not editable. Is there any other way to change it?

Comment: You can define a service level parameter to define a scope..eg: <parameter name="wsDiscoveryParams">
            <Scopes>http://public.ims.traderpauls.com/sales/dynamic_pricing</Scopes>
        </parameter>     The following guide explains the steps & theory well...http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/08/rediscover-soa-wso2-carbon-wsdiscovery

Comment: Ratha,
very interesting and useful to use the ws-discovery. Could tell me where I can configure the services scopes  in WSO2 Application Server (AS) tool?

Comment: Whatever the service hosted in AS, you must have a service meta file(service.xml)..You can define above parameter there. Or else, after uploading the service to AS, you can define the scope parameter via management console.

Comment: I understood, Ratha
I'm with another doubt that isn't related with that but if you could help me I would appreciate it.
We needed to provide a tool where our customers (people) could search for published services. We're trying to use the Governance Registry but do not know the correct way to do so. Could you tell me where to find an example?